# Error code=H10 status=503 occurred after deploying my react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku

I started my react project using npm create-react-app command. once I finished and locally tested my app, I deployed it to heroku by connecting my github repository. Everything went smoothly. But once i open the app for the first time, it worked, but afterwards an application error occurred and app crashed. This is the error log.[view error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CGbU.jpg)

how can I solve this problem. I used firebase as my database service.

Comment: I finally found the issue. The issue is with the buildpack. I didn’t use the correct build back when deploy the project. The problem was solved after re-deploying it using “creat-react-app” buildpack

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue. The issue is with the buildpack. I didn’t use the correct build back when deploy the project. The problem was solved after re-deploying it using “creat-react-app” buildpack

Here I am attaching the url of that buildpack

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack